# Dealing with SPAM: 6 (or more?) spam flags should destroy the user instead of the -100 penalty

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

Before you downvote, I don't propose that any user that gets spam flagged would be instantly destroyed. Read on.

In the recent spam wave, I've noticed how the flagging system works. People very quickly reach the magic 6 spam flag count, and the post gets annihilated. That's good.

However, there are problems with that:

- These spam flags get cleared from the queue. So mods won't see them nor be able to destroy the user effectively, without some sort of pointer, or manual lookup at the recent flags.
- Spam flags induce a -100 reputation penalty, which is 100% useless since the user always have 1 reputation point, and will not get lower.

My suggestion is as follow, if ALL of the following are true:

- The user only has one post.
- The user only has one reputation (meaning that his only post was never upvoted).
- The user's only post has reached 6 (or more?) spam flags
- The user registered less than a week ago.

If all of the above are correct, the user should be **automatically destroyed**. That's what us mods do, why not automate the process?

Comment: Flagged this question as spam so that...oh wait

Comment: So the spammers have to make 2 posts at a time to make sure they're not destroyed? Yay, more spam!

Comment: I don't know how much destroying the account actually helps. Account creation doesn't seem to slow them down much - and might actually allow them to post faster by evading the post rate-limits. Not sure of the impact on "analyzability" of the data post-nuke.

Comment: @Mat: This can actually be combined with my other suggestion, the hellban one, but it's risky. The point is to allow the automation of spammer destruction, without having to potentially wait for a moderator to notice.

Comment: If your additional conditions make this different than Mad Scientist's feature request, let me know and I'll remove the duplicate. I think they're asking for fundamentally the same thing, though.

Comment: @BradLarson: I liked how his post got +18 and mine +8-8 :D. Let me read through his

Answer (score 17):

Allowing users to delete someone else's account - and even if it's just a new one-rep one-post account - is a horrible idea.

It would make much more sense to suspend such an account automatically for maybe one day and raise a new flag for mods to check. At least on big sites that would be enough time to destroy the account without it being able to post more spam.

Comment: But then you accomplish nothing. By the time you reach the flag and destroy the user, the user already opened a new account and started spamming again. The only time you're wasting is your own.

Comment: He'd do exactly the same thing when destroying his account automatically.

Comment: That's right, but then ***you*** don't have to deal with it. Remember, the point is to make the spammer's life harder, not our mods!

Comment: @ThiefMaster "Allowing users to delete someone else's account - and even if it's just a new one-rep one-post account - is a horrible idea." - says a moderator... >.<